# NullPointerException on EditText widget in Fragment

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-edittext

I'm pretty new to Android App Dev, so the mistake is probably really simple, but my code is throwing a NullPointerException at this line of my code

```
    String reactant = reactants.getText().toString();
```

I am assuming that this is because the "reactants" EditText widget is still null from its declaration, but I don't understand why because I declared it in the onCreateView() method. Any help on how I'm supposed to fix this would be appreciated.

Here is my java and layout XML code.

**Java**

```
    public class stoich_fragment extends Fragment
    {
    View rootview;
    int i = 0;
    int l = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> elements = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean getElements = true;
    String s = "";
    String element = "";
    EditText reactants;
    TextView beq;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stoich_layout, container, false);
        reactants = (EditText) rootview.findViewById(R.id.reactants);
        beq = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.balanced_equation);
        return rootview;
    }
    String reactant = reactants.getText().toString();
    //saying that reactants is null even after it went through the onCreateView method
    String re = reactant.replaceAll("\\s+","");
    public void getReactants()
    {
        while(getElements)
        {
            String let = re.substring(i, i+1);
            if(let.compareTo(let.toLowerCase()) > 0)
            {
                element += let;
                i++;
            }
            else if(let.compareTo(let.toLowerCase()) == 0)
            {
                element += let;
                i++;
            }
            else if (let.equals("0")||let.equals("1")||let.equals("2")||let.equals("3")||let.equals("4")||let.equals("5")||let.equals("6")||let.equals("7")||let.equals("8")||let.equals("9"))
            {
                int temp = Integer.parseInt(let);
                arr.add(temp);
                elements.add(element);
                element = "";
            }
            else if(i > re.length()-1)
            {
                getElements = false;
            }
        }
        // displays the elements isolated on the reactant side
        // to test to make sure my logic works
        for(int a = 0; a<re.length(); a++)
        {
            s += elements.get(a) + " : " + arr.get(a) + "\n";
        }
        beq.setText(s);
    }
    }
```

**XML**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/reactants"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="95dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/products"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/reactants"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/balanced_equation"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="30sp" />
<!--should make text bold and black-->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Balancing Equations"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: In which method do you call String reactant = reactants.getText().toString(); ?

Comment: `String reactant = reactants.getText().toString();` is outside of a method. You might want to fix that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring `String reactant = reactants.getText().toString();` outside of any method, which means it will get executed before your `onCreateView()` method is executed, which is where you inflate the layout that holds this view. You can't access a view to set/get its contents until it has been inflated. The solution is to call `String reactant = reactants.getText().toString();` sometime after these lines:

```
rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stoich_layout, container, false);
reactants = (EditText) rootview.findViewById(R.id.reactants);
```

Of course the String will be empty if you haven't entered in any text, but this will at least let you legitimately check without getting a NullPointerException.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed my problem

Comment: Glad it helped! Please accept this answer if you feel it helped solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just because the code in written vertically, doesn't mean it is executed vertically.

You have essentially done this

```
EditText reactants; // <--- Null here
String reactant = reactants.getText().toString(); // <-- error here
String re = reactant.replaceAll("\\s+","");

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stoich_layout, container, false);
    reactants = (EditText) rootview.findViewById(R.id.reactants);
    beq = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.balanced_equation);
    return rootview;
}
```

Solution would be to move the error-causing line into a method where you need that String variable.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `String reactant = reactants.getText().toString();` at the class level (same as if you moved it up above onCreateView), meaning it happens before any methods in the class are called, so onCreateView hasn't happened yet and the textview has not been inflated - so you are calling getText on a null variable.